# How a save in a list the elements of a first list that are not contained in a second list with duplicate values?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-7

I have a problem with a heuristic for Virtual Graph where I have to count the elements of numbers from two integer lists: **I have to put in a list the numbers of the first one and the numbers that are not in the second list.**

I've tried with two addAll and a removeAll(secondList) and it works but when the lists have **duplicates** It doesn't work because removes the duplicate element too:

```java
        //Test lists
        List<Integer> ls1 = Arrays.asList(1,1,2,3);
        List<Integer> ls3 = Arrays.asList(1,3);
        List<Integer> s = new ArrayList<>();

        s.addAll(ls1);
        System.out.println("Add " + ls1);
        s.addAll(ls3);
        System.out.println("Add " + ls3);
        System.out.println("New list" + s);
        s.removeAll(ls3);
        System.out.println("Expected value (1,2)");
        System.out.println("Result List " + s);
```

The new list is [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3] and the expected output is [1,2] but the actual output is only 2.

Comment: Why don't you iterate the list ls1 and add the elements in the new list only when there is no previous instance of it ?

Comment: Take a look at `List#retainAll` and what a `Set` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove elements present in `ls2` from `ls1` as :

```
List<Integer> ls1 = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> ls2 = Arrays.asList(1, 3);
List<Integer> s = new ArrayList<>(ls1);
ls2.forEach(s::remove);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Guillermo Garrido,

It looks like you want to substract list two from list one.

If you are using `apache-commons` in your project then you can do it simply by following line :

```
import import org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils;
List<Integer> s = ListUtils.subtract(ls1, ls2);
```

Or if you want to do it using simple java then look at @Naman 's answer.